# Criar uma Activity e nela chamar vários Layouts pode ser prejudicial?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

Como ainda estou caminhando no estudo de aplicações Android e li coisas a este respeito, gostaria de saber se, por exemplo, eu tiver apenas uma Activity e vários layouts sendo chamados a partir dela, há risco de a aplicação não estar de acordo com as boas práticas.

No código abaixo eu tenho o layout principal da Activity e mais outros dois sendo chamados. Nesses dois adicionais, há botões que permitem que eu mude a tela tanto para um quanto para outro layout adicional.

Há ainda um áudio, que é iniciado quando troco a tela do layout principal para o layout activity_a, e recebe o stop quando acesso a layout activity_b.

Isso pode ser prejudicial em algum aspecto?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button btn_iniciar;
private RelativeLayout activity_a, activity_b;
private MediaPlayer player;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    CarregarTelaPrincipal();

}
public void CarregarTelaPrincipal() {

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn_iniciar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_iniciar);

    btn_iniciar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CarregarLetraA();
        }
    });
}

public void CarregarLetraA() {

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_a);
    activity_a = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_a);

    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.keyboard);
    player.start();

    activity_a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            player.stop();
            CarregarLetraB();
        }

    });
}

public void CarregarLetraB() {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_b);
    activity_b = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_b);
    activity_b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CarregarTelaPrincipal();
        }
    });
}

}
```

Comment: Complexidade desnecessária. Preocupação extra por bobagem. Se voce for usar o método onBackPressed (que é chamado quando se clica no botão < "para trás" do android),por exemplo, então vai ter que ficar fazendo checagens e mais checagens.
Se você precisar ir de uma tela A para uma tela B, vai ter que ficar inventando animações pra dar a sensação de troca de tela (porque a tela não vai ser trocada).
As vezes é necessário manter uma tela ativa enquanto outra a sobrepoem pra depois voltar...Você seria incapaz de iniciar uma activity que espera um resultado (startActivityForResult)

Answer (score 4):

Sim, é "prejudicial" e não deve usar.

Desde logo porque vai contra o primeiro principio do [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29): uma classe deve ter uma só responsabilidade.
O próprio nome Activity(Actividade) sugere isso mesmo.

A cada *Activity* deve corresponder um *layout*, com a respectiva lógica para o manipular.
Com isso se consegue:

- Reduzir a complexidade do código.
- Maior legibilidade.
- Redução de acoplamento.
- Código limpo e testável.
- Facilidade de evolução.

Lembre que o método `findViewById()` apenas encontra as *views* que estão dentro do *layout* indicado no método `setContentView()`.

Numa situação simples, como é o exemplo da pergunta, até pode "dar" para gerir o código de forma a que não quebre devido às mudanças de *Layout,* mas com o aumento da complexidade isso torna-se difícil.

Se quiser ter apenas uma *Activity* use um [Fragment](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html) para cada um dos *layouts*.

Isolando o código que manipula cada *layout* em uma nova classe(Fragment), distribui as responsabilidades, deixando para a *Activity* apenas a de gerir quando apresentar cada um deles.

Answer (score 0):

Não vejo como prejudicial.

Talvez você tenha problemas, caso necessite implementar o `onStop()` ou `onPause()` nesta mesma classe da `Activity`.

Porém, para esta funcionalidade, você já considerou o uso de [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html?hl=pt-br)?

Já que elas possuem seu próprio ciclo de vida.

Comment: *Não é prejudicial, mas tem problemas, considere usar Fragments.* Fiquei sem saber qual é a sua posição, deve ser usado ou não?

Comment: É uma pergunta se vai impactar na aplicação de alguma forma... minha resposta é não! Só acho que para o uso que ele deseja fazê-la aconselho a  implementação dos Fragments.

Comment: Referente aos "problemas" eu considero porque eu não sei como ele vai codificar nos outros ciclos de vida. Já que todas os layouts dele estão no `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 0):

O correto seria utilizar `Fragments`, os fragments são classes que possuem um Layout e necessitam de uma Activity para funcionar.

Um fragment precisa de um "Manager" que vai gerir as transições entre um e outro, fazendo com que não haja problemas com memória por exemplo.

Além disto, você pode separar suas "Views" em várias classes, mantendo assim mais organizado.

Caso queira, pode pesquisar um pouco sobre a utilização do `ViewPager` (Se estiver usando o Android Studio, crie uma "TabedActivity" dos exemplos dele)